# Modeling UML in Visio: connectors (associations, etc.) don't move along when class is moved

Tags: diagrams, microsoft-visio-2013, uml

Here's the steps to reproduce my scenario:

1. Open Visio 2013, start a new UML diagram.
2. Add one class.
3. Add another class.
4. Add an association between the two classes.

   *The diagram should now look like this:*

   [image: two classes connected with an association]
5. Move the rightmost class a bit downwards.

   **Result:** connector hasn't moved along. See:

   [image: two classes seemingly unconnected]

   **Expected**: The association should've stuck to the second class.

The reason I'm writing this as a SU question and not a bug on MS Connect is twofold. First, I'm afraid I'm missing something here and that I should use Visio differently to make the expected behavior work. Second, if this *is* a bug I'd still love to know if there's someone that knows a way around this.

I've tried searching ([[1]](https://www.google.nl/search?q=uml%20visio%20move%20class), [[2]](https://www.google.nl/search?q=Visio%20UML%20diagram%20connector%20won%27t%20move), [[3]](https://www.google.nl/search?q=Visio%20connector%20move%20along%20box)) as well as making the connector stick to various parts of the UML class box, none of it helps.

I've also repeated the experiment with two Flowchart Process Shapes,  and an *UML* directed association between the two: in this case the connector *does* move along.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, only minutes after typing up that question, I fiddle some more and find the answer. Apparently Visio is very picky about what the connector sticks to. I was casually dragging the connector and linking it to the `ClassName` bit, like so:

[image: glueing to the ClassName]

Instead, you should fiddle with your mouse, until you see this:

[image: glueing to the Class]

The easiest way I found so far to do this is moving your mouse to the left edge of the Class box until the green line surrounds the entire thing.

Leaving this up here, hoping it may help someone else too.

Comment: This answer helped me to some extent, but Visio's behavior for (re)routing connectors is so infuriatingly quirky that I gave up using it for this purpose. So just a friendly tip: bring lots of patience to the table if you're going to model UML with Visio!

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I found another way that works even better. Instead of glueing the association to the shape glue it to these black points in the middle of the edge of the shape. This way you can determine on which side the association should stick.

Comment: @Dakkaron glad to hear it helped. Feel free to edit your suggestion into the answer to make it more complete!